# Pulling down BigQuery table schema on each element is slow using Beam/Dataflow

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

The following is my code which reads CSV file with 1000 rows and writes them into BQ table:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PipelineOptionsFactory.register(TemplateOptions.class);
        TemplateOptions options = PipelineOptionsFactory.fromArgs(args).withValidation().as(TemplateOptions.class);
        options.setZone("europe-west1-c");
        options.setProject("myProject-dev");
        options.setRunner(DataflowRunner.class);
        Pipeline pipeline = Pipeline.create(options);
        pipeline.apply("READ", TextIO.read().from("gs://myBucket/LOG_EBM_1000.csv"))
                .apply("TRANSFORM", ParDo.of(new WikiParDo()))
                .apply("WRITE", BigQueryIO.writeTableRows()
                                .to("myProject:DF_TEST.LOG_EBM_PM")
                                .withCreateDisposition(CreateDisposition.CREATE_NEVER).withWriteDisposition(WRITE_APPEND)
                                );
        pipeline.run().waitUntilFinish();
    }

    private static Schema getTableSchema() {
        List<TableFieldSchema> fields = new ArrayList<>();
        // The name for the new dataset and Table
        String datasetId = "DF_TEST";
        String tableId = "LOG_EBM_PM";
        BigQuery bigQuery = BigQueryOptions.getDefaultInstance().getService();
        return bigQuery.getTable(datasetId, tableId).getDefinition().getSchema();
    }

    public interface TemplateOptions extends DataflowPipelineOptions {
        @Description("GCS path of the file to read from")
        ValueProvider<String> getInputFile();
        void setInputFile(ValueProvider<String> value);

        @Description("My custom command line argument.")
        @Default.String("D-FAULT")
        String getMyCustomOption();
        void setMyCustomOption(String myCustomOption);
    }

    private static class WikiParDo extends DoFn<String, TableRow> {
        @ProcessElement
        public void processElement(ProcessContext c) throws Exception {
            String[] split = c.element().split(",");
            TableRow row = new TableRow();
            for (int i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {
                Field col = getTableSchema().getFields().get(i);
                row.set(col.getName(), split[i]);
            }
            c.output(row);
        }
    }
```

the following is the screanshot of the pipline when it was executing the task:
[image]

As you see, the **Transform** task has Wall time of 1:45 minutes.In the definition of wall time is written:

> Approximate time spent in this step on initializing, processing data, shuffling data, and terminating, across all threads in all workers. For composite steps, the sum of time spent in the component steps. This estimate helps you identify slow steps.

The execution of whole pipline takes around 10 minutes in total for 1000 rows using the machine type: **n1-highcpu-16**.

In my final CSV files we will have milions of records(file size around 2GB ), so the pipline should works much faster. What is wrong with my pipline which it is that much slow even if I am using a high CPU machine??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code calls `getTableSchema()` (which makes an API call to the BigQuery service) for each field of each row - many thousands of identical (and thus redundant) BigQuery API calls. It looks like you're also *establishing a connection to BigQuery* (`getService()`) many thousands of times. That's why it's slow.

You can progressively speed it up in several ways:

- Do the call only once per processElement(): this will speed it up by a factor of (number of fields).
- Do the call only once per DoFn instance, by doing it in the DoFn's `@Setup` method and caching the result in a `transient` instance variable: this will speed it up by a further factor of several hundred.
- Do the call only once per pipeline, by doing it in your main program and passing the list of fields as a constructor argument to your DoFn:

Something like this:

```
class WikiParDo ... {
  private final List<String> fields;
  WikiParDo(List<String> fields) { this.fields = fields; }
    // in processElement method, use "fields" instead of calling 
    // "getTableSchema"
}

... main program: ...
TableSchema schema = getTableSchema();
List<String> fields = new ArrayList<>();
... populate fields from schema ...

p.apply(...)
 .apply(..., new WikiParDo(fields))
```

Comment: Thank you jkff  for your great answer :)